# Powershell invoke-sqlcmd only works with a dedicated administrator connection on Azure VM

Tags: sql, powershell, azure

I am trying to use Powershell and the Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet to do some basic database tasks, like detach a database, attach a new database, add users for the db for logins, etc.

I am scheduling a task to run this batch file with similar parameters to perform these tasks:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "C:\Tasks\DownloadDBFromFTP.ps1"^
 -sourcePath 'C:\FTPSource\'^
 -destinationPath 'C:\SQL\Attach\'^
 -destinationConnectionString 'Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Sth;Integrated Security=False;User ID=foo;Password=bar'^
 -zipFileName 'Sth_Primary.zip'
```

> Here is a snippet of DownloadDBFromFTP.ps1:

```
<# Detaches a database using a SQL Server Connection String. The Initial Catalog will be Detached. #>
Function DetachDatabase($connectionString)
{
    $sqlConnection = New-Object system.data.sqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder($connectionString)
    $databaseName = $sqlConnection.InitialCatalog

    <# Set Database to SINGLE_USER and Close all connectsion #>
    $singleUserQuery = @"USE [master] GO ALTER DATABASE $databaseName SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"@

    Write-Host "Set Database $databaseName To Single User Mode"
    try 
    {
        Invoke-Sqlcmd $singleUserQuery -QueryTimeout 3600 -ServerInstance $sqlConnection.DataSource -Username $sqlConnection.UserID -Password $sqlConnection.Password
    }
    catch 
    {
        # $_ is set to the ErrorRecord of the exception
        if ($_.Exception.InnerException) 
        {
            Write-Host $_.Exception.InnerException.Message
        } 
        else 
        {
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
```

These operations execute from one of our Azure VMs just fine with no errors, but for some reason that I cannot determine a different Azure VM is throwing an error, regardless of the query. Here I tried a basic "SELECT GETDATE()" and I get an overflow or divide by 0 error:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
At F:\PowershellDBTransfer\DownloadDBFromFTP.ps1:71 char:3
+         Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query ("SELECT GETDATE()") -QueryTimeout 3600  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], OverflowException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

As a last ditch effort, we tried using the -DedicatedAdministratorConnection parameter for Invoke-Sqlcmd and it ran fine. One of our DB devs strongly advised against this, so I am trying to get a clue as to what is different about this particular VM.